# Navi app launched from activity and return to back on pressing back button and again launch navi but activity gets destroyed

Tags: android

I am getting error.when I run map using below steps.
1. Launch navi map by broadcast intent from activity
2. Return to activity by pressing back button on navi app
3. Again launch navi by broadcast intent from same activity
4.but activity is destroy after broadcast second time to launch map

Comment: Nice story. Would you like to ask a question?

Answer (score 0):

Use recreate() method to start activity again.

[Here you can see.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29)

Comment: And when you back from another activity use finish() method to remove it from stack.

Comment: Thanks for giving solution i tried it is not working